# Send Recorded Audio File to Web Server With PHP

Tags: php, javascript, audio, upload, wav

I'm using [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) which allows users to create their own sound recording from their microphone input. I'm new to this so I'm using [this site](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html) as a point of reference.

This code creates a downloadable .wav file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/recorderjs/recorder.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="record" src="mic.png" onclick="toggleRecording(this);"><br>

        <img src="save.svg" onclick="saveAudio();">

        <form action="savefile.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This starts and stops the recording:

```
<img id="record" src="mic.png" onclick="toggleRecording(this);">
```

And this downloads the .wav file from the recorder.js script:

```
<img src="save.svg" onclick="saveAudio();">
```

I'm using this PHP script to try and save the .wav file to the /audio directory:

```
<?php

$save_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . "/audio";
if(! file_exists($save_folder)) {
    if(! mkdir($save_folder)) {
        die("failed to create save folder $save_folder");
    }
}

$key = 'filename';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["audiofile"]["tmp_name"];
$upload_name = $_FILES["audiofile"]["name"];
$type = $_FILES["audiofile"]["type"];
$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
$saved = 0;
if(($type == 'audio/x-wav' || $type == 'application/octet-stream') && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.wav$/', $upload_name) ) {

    $saved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename) ? 1 : 0;
}

?>
```

Now, what I'm hoping for is someone to help me with a PHP script which uploads the .wav files to the folder /audio instead of having the user download the file.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Enijar,  Are You able to save the recorded file on server. How you did that. can you please share that code. Thanks

Comment: please share that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can't use usuall http file fields, because they expect a local path.
You could try a upload with AJAX.

```
var req = null;
var url = "savefile.php";
var data = "":   // you have to check how to get the data from your saveAudio() method

(window.XMLHttpRequest) ? req = new XMLHttpRequest() : (window.ActiveXObject) ? req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : req = false; 
req.open(method, url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

if(data != null && data != "")
{
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
  req.send(data);
}
```

You yust need to find out how you can get the filecontent from your `saveAudio()` function and fill it into the `data` variable.

And maybe this can help you too [uploading files with ajax](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/)